# android studio 3.0 noting show any things in device file explorer

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-3.0

in android studio 3.0 preview canary 4 nothing show any thing of my device in new device file explorer in android studio 3. 
i enable USB debugging and can run my app and can show file in DDMS. 
[image]

Comment: have you solve this problem?

Comment: @Abdulwahid no still we have this problem

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Android Studio 3.0.1, but was hitting the same problem with one of my connected devices. The clue was that this was an Android device that I had rooted.

If you are using an app like SuperSU, try *disabling* SU permissions for ADB Shell, then reconnect your Android device to your dev computer via a USB cable.
You should now be able to see a list a files in "Device File Explorer".

(See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/48166524/8740835 )