# Android Studio 3 (All Versions) - Device file explorer nothing to show

Tags: file, android-studio

When opening the `Device file explorer` window in Android Studio Preview 3, I don't see the device's files (There is a message "Nothing to show").
I searched this topic a lot but couldn't find anything that is relevant to this issue.

*I'm using my test device:*

> Android Galaxy S5 running Android OS 6 (API 23) - Rooted

*The specific build of Android Studio I'm using is:*

> Android Studio 3.0 Beta 6
>   
> Build #AI-171.4333198, built on September 13, 2017
>   
> JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-915-b01 amd64
>   
> JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
>   
> Windows 10 10.0

Any idea's how to solve this issue?

Comment: Have you solved this problem?

Comment: @CoXier
Unfortunately not... as you can see nobody responded...

Comment: Same issue with the stable release of 3.0 and a rooted Lanix X110 here

Comment: @henengel Could you edit the title of this question to better indicate that it applies to all versions of Android Studio 3.x (at least as far as v3.3)

Comment: @AndrewD Done... Thank you for the suggestions...

Answer (score 41, accepted):

After struggling with this for a day, the answer for me was associated with *disabling* SuperUser permissions for the ADB shell on my Android Device.

If you have rooted your device and are using an app like SuperSU, try disabling the SU permission for ADB shell in the apps view list.

1. First disconnect your Android device from the computer running Android Studio
2. On your Android device open SuperSU and select the apps tab.
3. Click on ADB shell and select Access:'deny'
4. Reconnect your device to your dev computer using a USB cable
5. In Android Studio open the "Device File Explorer".

You should now see a list of files on the device, including files in /data/data/ and its subfolders

You would think that having SU permissions would be a good thing: but in this case, no.

[Disable ADB shell's SU permissions in SuperSU](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w4yzJ.png)

Comment: Thanks it worked, I'd really love to know why SU affects File Explorer access though.

Comment: It would be a reasonable guess that rooted devices are just not part of Google's test suite. I expect that AndroidStudio3 has a set of test conditions before allowing access to the normally protected folders, and a rooted device happens to fail one of those conditions.

Comment: this solution may be for  SU rooted devices. are there any other solutions?

Comment: Thanks it's worked for me. It should be the accept answer

Comment: I didn't have ADB Shell in the apps list in SuperSU, so I just switched off SuperSU altogether in `SuperSU -> Settings -> Enable superuser`. After that Device File Explorer started working.

Answer (score 9):

AS file explorer will execute `su 0 sh -c 'ls -l /'` to list the files. For unknown reason, `SuperSu` remove the single quotes and the actual command are `su 0 sh -c ls -l /`. In such case, the -l will not work. AS file explorer may have some problem to parse the output. So there is nothing to show. 
You can check the log of AS to get such behavior. Open the log from: help -> show log in explorer

Comment: how did you find out this info re: What AS file explorer sends to ADB?